# concatenate the argument of date into one string

Tags: command-line, scripts

my main program takes a time stamp having the format of the date as well as the time, separated by a comma, but it is still one string and one argument:

```
#source main.sh '2015-02-10 00:00:00'
```

Now, I want to give time stamp automatically to the program by running the following script. 
My problem is that, I should keep the space between the date and time and the output of the first line or the value of TIMESTAMP is two arguments, one for the date and the other of the time, which contradicts the permitted number of arguments passed to the main.sh.

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date --date='40 days ago' '+%F %T')
TARGET=/opt/db_maintain/main.sh
COMMAND=${TARGET}" "${TIMESTAMP}
#source $COMMAND
echo $TIMESTAMP
```

the output is:

```
   2015-02-04 15:55:50
```

Is there any way to join the date and the time of TIMESTAMP as only one argument? plz be informed that I should maintain the space between the time and the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

Please try the following snippet instead:

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date --date='40 days ago' '+%F %T')
TARGET=/opt/db_maintain/main.sh
source $TARGET "$TIMESTAMP"
```

---

To avoid quoting your TIMESTAMP argument why not using the [iso8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) `T` delimiter?

Date and time can be one string: `2014-02-04T13:49:40`

And you can use such format as date input:

```
$ date --date='2014-02-04T13:49:40' 
Tue Feb  4 13:49:40 CET 2014
```

If your target script can only understand datetime with a space, store it this way:

```
TIMESTAMP="$(printf "%q" "$(date --date='40 days ago' '+%F %T')")"
```

The space will be escaped:

```
$ echo $TIMESTAMP
2015-02-04\ 14:04:51
```

Alternatively you can escape quotes like this:

```
COMMAND="$TARGET \"$TIMESTAMP\""
```

Comment: no this does not help, if I add T between time and date, the T letter will be shown in the output print result, and it cannot be read in a sql command. your print statement also adds a / between date and time and it send error.

Comment: @user3313098 Please try my third proposal

Comment: I tried adding \" to the variable. strangely, when it creates two argument, the first $1 is "2015-02-04
and the second is 18:14:20"

Comment: @user3313098 I don't think you need to source your `/opt/db_maintain/main.sh` script, just call it with the full path

Comment: it won't work that way, it just prints it.

Comment: @user3313098 one last try :), See my update

Comment: Yes, that's it.But this looks so confusing to me. why doesn't it give the same output with "$TARGET \"$TIMESTAMP\"" ! this punctuations symbols should theoretically have the same effect as putting the variable directly inside double quotes!